# What is the correct value for LDAPbinddn in Bugzilla LDAP integration?

Tags: ldap, bugzilla

I have a new Bugzilla installation, and trying to connect it to my LDAP server.

Can't seem to make it work.

What is the correct value of this field: LDAPbinddn  should be?

- I am able to bind with LDAP browser with the user:

  company\administrator

  password

[image]

so I tried the value as:

```
cn=administrator;cn=Company_Users;dc=company:password
```

I get the error:

```
Failed to bind to the LDAP server. The error message was: 80090308
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of 2 guides [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/ldap-guide.html) and [Error description](http://www.websina.com/bugzero/faq/ldap-error-code-49.html) I understood my mistake.

The correct LDAP string should have been:

```
cn=Administrator,cn=users,dc=Company:password
```